# Randomizing 1s and 0s by groups while specifiying proportion of 1 and 0 within groups

Tags: r, random, sample, group

First, I want to create a column that randomize 1s and 0s by group while maintaining the same proportion of 1s and 0s in another column.

Second, I want to repeat the above procedure many times (say 1000) and calculate the expected value.

Let me clarify with hypothetical data.

```
library(data.table) 

district <- c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,3,3)                                       
village <- c(1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5,6,7)                              
status <- c(1,0,1,0, 1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0) 

datei <- data.table(district, village, status)
```

What I want to do is I want to create a column that randomize 1s and 0s within a district while
maintaining the same proportion of 1s and 0s in status; the proportions of 1:0 are 2:2, 3:2 and 4:3 in
district 1, 2 and 3 respectively.

Second, I also want to repeat this randomization many times (say 1000 times) and calculate the expected value for each row.

I know how to randomize 1s and 0s based on district.

```
datei[, random_status := sample(c(1,0), .N, replace=TRUE), keyby = district]
```

However, I do not know how to have the same proportion of 1s and 0s as in status and how to repeat and calculate the expected values for each row.

Many thanks.

Edit:
Let me add what I expect regarding calculating the expected values for each raw after, say, 1000 repetitions.  Column exp_status is generated after randomizing many times while keeping the proportion of 1:0 within district is the same as in status.

| district | village | status | exp_status |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 0.9 |
| 1 | 2 | 0 | 0.7 |
| 1 | 3 | 1 | 0.8 |
| 1 | 4 | 0 | 0.1 |
| 2 | 1 | 1 | 0.2 |
| 2 | 2 | 1 | 0.3 |
| 2 | 3 | 1 | 0.2 |
| 2 | 4 | 0 | 0.9 |
| 2 | 5 | 0 | 0.8 |
| 3 | 1 | 1 | 0.4 |
| 3 | 2 | 1 | 0.5 |
| 3 | 3 | 1 | 0.9 |
| 3 | 4 | 1 | 0.8 |
| 3 | 5 | 0 | 0.9 |
| 3 | 6 | 0 | 0.8 |
| 3 | 7 | 0 | 0.7 |

Comment: If you keep the ratios constant in each district, then why bother randomly assorting/simulating - the expected outcome is defined in your setup? a 2:2 ratio of 1:0 give an expected value of 0.5; a 3:2 gives 0.6, and a 4:3 gives ~0.57 (4/7).  Have I misunderstood?

Comment: @PaulStaffordAllen  When I think about it further, yes, you're right. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a `table` as `prob=`, which gives on large scale similar proportions.

```
set.seed(42)
datei[, random_status := sample(0:1, .N, replace=TRUE, prob=table(status)), keyby = district]

colMeans(datei[, 3:4])
      #  status random_status 
      # 0.56339       0.56277
```

---

*Data:*

*(slightly blown up, to 1e5 rows)*

```
datei <- structure(list(district = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 
3, 3, 3, 3, 3), village = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 
3, 4, 5, 6, 7), status = c(1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 0, 0, 0)), row.names = c(NA, -16L), class = c("data.table", 
"data.frame"))

set.seed(42)
datei <- datei[sample.int(nrow(datei), 1e5, replace=TRUE), ]
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. But, what I want is expected value for each row.

Comment: @Alfa Simulating this would seem to be pointless - the expected value for each row is defined in your question - if the ratios in district 1 are always 2:2 0s to 1s, then the expected value for each row is 0.5, surely?

Comment: @PaulStaffordAllen  When I think about it again, yes, it's pointless. You're correct.

Answer (score 0):

The default behavior of `sample` is exactly what you are looking for, i.e. reshuffling:

```r
library(dplyr)
datei |> 
  mutate(random_status = sample(status), .by = district)

#or
library(data.table)
datei[, random_status := sample(status), district]
```

As for the second question, I join @Paul Stafford Allen's comment in that it will always be .5, as per the [law of large numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_large_numbers).

Comment: Oh, the law of large numbers. Now, I understand. Thank you.